# Simplest, bare-bones HTTP2 Server example based on nghttp2

Tags: http2, nghttp2

Anybody has a pointer to an example that implements a HTTP2 Server (in clear text mode) using nghttp2 ?

Answer (score 2):

It depends how you want to implement this.

The easiest way is to use the [nghttpd command](https://nghttp2.org/documentation/nghttpd.1.html):

```
 nghttpd --no-tls 80
```

This is the easiest way of getting a HTTP/2 server up and running to test client implementations. You can also add the `-v` switch to use verbose mode and log all the frames used.

If you want to write the server in C then the [example in the documentation](https://nghttp2.org/documentation/tutorial-server.html) is a HTTPS server, so this would need to be adapted for clear text (h2c).

Finally there is a much easier [C++ implementation in the documentation](https://nghttp2.org/documentation/libnghttp2_asio.html).